# Can't encode Array from the output I got from a PHP script to Json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL database called 'plan_test', which contains tables called (5a, 5b, 5c...). These tables have the same columns and multiple rows. I've setup an user with the permissions to do everything with the database. Here is my php code, which should return a json formated String, that I can read later on:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tester";
$password = "abc123";
$dbname = "plan_test";

$sql = "select * from plan_test.5a";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    array_push($response,array("Klasse"=>$row[0],"Tag"=>$row[4],"Monat"=>$row[5],"Stundenanfang"=>$row[7],"Stundenende"=>$row[8],"Art"=>$row[9],"Fach"=>$row[10],"Lehrer"=>$row[11],"sFach"=>$row[12],"sLehrer"=>$row[13],"Raum"=>$row[14],"Bemerkung"=>$row[15]));

}
echo json_encode(array("test"=>$response));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I am getting a blank site out of it and when I run

```
var_dump($response);
```

I get this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    ["Klasse"]=>
    string(2) "5a"
    ["Tag"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["Monat"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["Stundenanfang"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Stundenende"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Art"]=>
    string(10) "Vertretung"
    ["Fach"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["Lehrer"]=>
    string(2) "VH"
    ["sFach"]=>
    string(1) "E"
    ["sLehrer"]=>
    string(2) "AL"
    ["Raum"]=>
    string(3) "113"
    ["Bemerkung"]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
    ["Klasse"]=>
    string(2) "5a"
    ["Tag"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["Monat"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["Stundenanfang"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Stundenende"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["Art"]=>
    string(10) "Vertretung"
    ["Fach"]=>
    string(4) "SCHW"
    ["Lehrer"]=>
    string(2) "WE"
    ["sFach"]=>
    string(4) "SCHW"
    ["sLehrer"]=>
    string(2) "TO"
    ["Raum"]=>
    string(3) "AH2"
    ["Bemerkung"]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(12) {
    ["Klasse"]=>
    string(2) "5a"
    ["Tag"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["Monat"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["Stundenanfang"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Stundenende"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["Art"]=>
    string(10) "Vertretung"
    ["Fach"]=>
    string(4) "SCHW"
    ["Lehrer"]=>
    string(2) "RR"
    ["sFach"]=>
    string(4) "SCHW"
    ["sLehrer"]=>
    string(2) "WI"
    ["Raum"]=>
    string(3) "AH1"
    ["Bemerkung"]=>
    string(1) "�"
  }
}
```

For some reason this array was not encoded to a json format.
How do I encode this array to a json String?

Btw that undefined String from 'Bemerkung' is meant to be there.

Comment: echo $json = json_encode($response); ?

Comment: where `var_dump()`?

Comment: @Blueline nope..

Comment: @MrKen tried before the encode and after the encode.. nothing changed.

Comment: Try adding an `echo json_last_error_msg();` at the end. There are some broken characters in your var_dump output, they might be invalid UTF-8.

Comment: You try `$json = json_encode(array("test"=>$response));` and after `var_dump($json);`

Comment: not sure, but could `string(1) "�"` be causing an encoding error?

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$response` to be the encoded version, you `echo` the encoded version of `$response`. That is why `var_dump()` shows an array.

And to output actual JSON you'll have to add the appropriate `Content-Type` header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("test"=>$response));
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a malformed UTF-8 characters..
thx @Vatev

Answer (score 0):

You are using the mysqli_fetch_array function, you can guess from his name that this function will return an PHP array ;)

You need to transform your PHP array into a json string, the json_encode
function will do the job for you.

From your php you need to add the header `content-type: application/json` to specify in the response returned to the client that the body is in json. With that the client browser will be able to properly read the data.

What is the value in database for column Bemerkung at the third line. I think it's an accent or something and you maybe have an encoding problem

Answer (score 0):

I think , you must use mysqli_fetch_all() like this.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "tester";
$password = "abc123";
$dbname = "plan_test";

$sql = "select * from plan_test.5a";

$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf-8");
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = mysqli_fetch_all();

echo json_encode($response);

mysqli_close($con);
```

I couldn't test the script , but it must solve your problem.